# Access Dynamic entry form

Tags: ms-access, dynamic

First off my Access skills are sub-par, but I'm fairly certain that it is the direction I need to go for my project so I'm hoping I can get some feedback to direct my research. I am however well versed at Excel, VBA and Matlab so I'm not completely incapable, I hope.

I need to assemble a system to track emissions (chemicals) from a variety of sources (units). Each unit has its own set of possible emissions and they need to be tracked daily (but also have the capability to be entered for multiple days at the same time).

What I would ideally like to have is an entry form that initially has 2 dropdown boxes, one to select the month/year and the other to select the unit.

Once selected I would like to auto populate a table that has the entire months dates in column 1, and then all of the possible emissions for that unit in the next 2:N columns. Then I would like to query the existing database to populate any data that has already been entered for the date/unit combination.

At this point need to let the users input new data, either for just one day or for numerous days. Then save it to the database.

I have approximately 70 possible emissions and approximately 40 units. I will need to be able to add new units and specify their chemicals as well as add new chemicals to existing units as their duties change. I would also like the ability for multiple users to be entering data simultaneously, which I believe is a hallmark of Access and may not be something I have to "turn on".

I hope that there is a way that Access can help me do this and not necessitate using Excel (which is very clunky in this case).

Thanks in advance,

Ben

The format for the data can simply be:

```
Date      Unit    Chemical1    Chemical2    Chemical3
1/1/16    UnitA    0            0.1          0
1/1/16    UnitB    0            0.3          0.2
1/1/16    UnitC    0.2          0            0.5
```

I'll need to do more analysis of the data, but given it as shown would be more than sufficient for the remainder of the work.

For the data entry from I would like to have two drop down boxes: (1) Month/Year and (2) Unit Name. And then the form that the users would fill in would list each day of the month in the left-most column and then give all of the chems that unit could emit in the following columns.
So  if: 
Unit1 was able to emit ChemA and ChemC
Unit2 was able to emit ChemB
Unit3 was able to emit ChemA, ChemB, and ChemC

So the entry form for Jan-2016 for Unit1 would give them the following assuming today is the 3rd and they have entered data for the 1 and 2.

```
(1)Jan-2016       (2)UnitA
Date       ChemA       ChemC
1/1         0.1         0.2
1/2         0.2         0.1
1/3
```

Then selecting unit 2 would change the available columns and again show the last 2 days entries and allow for the entry of today

```
(1)Jan-2016       (2)Unit2
Date       ChemB       
1/1         0.1         
1/2         0.2     
1/3
```

Finally Unit3 has all 3 chemicals available and would show the previous data and the blank entries.

```
(1)Jan-2016       (2)UnitB
Date       ChemA       ChemB       ChemC
1/1         0.1         0.1         0.1         
1/2         0.2         0.2         0.2 
1/3
```

I don't mind (and would prefer) that all of the dates for a month were populated and not just the next date. So that January would have 31 rows, Feb would have 29 (this year), etc, etc.

01-21-2016
Wayne, my current tables are:

UnitList

```
ID    UnitName    UnitOwner    UnitLocation    UnitDesc    AllowedChems
```

The last column AllowedChems, is a multiple selection that is linked to the table ChemicalList which looks like:

```
ID    ChemicalName    MassUnit    Type
```

Where all of the entries from ChemicalName are possible selection in the AllowedChems field of UnitList

Then I have a table called Tracking with the columns:

```
ID    EDate    UName    Vent    ThOx
```

At the end of this list I would like to have a column for each of the chemicals listed in ChemicalList, that way the users can input a number for the mass of that chemical they are emitting and it will be transferred to the correct column. But I'm as yet unable to determine if I'm able to build columns by linking them to the contents of another table. Perhaps there is another way around this?

For example if my chemicals are listed in the ChemicalList table as:

```
ID    ChemName   
1     ChemA
2     ChemB
3     ChemC
```

Then I want the Tracking table to look like:

```
ID    EDate    UName    Vent    ThOx    ChemA    ChemB    ChemC
```

And grow each time a new chemical is added.

Comment: Updated original question

Comment: I suggest you have separate tables for: (1) Unit Info; (2) Chemical Info; (3) Allowed Chemicals by Unit; (4) and finally 'Chemicals by unit details'. You say '...query existing DB to populate data already entered...' - where is that coming from? Once you have the proper tables created and populated, your form can generate the proper combinations. Your form could also double as a data entry form. Is this close to what you are thinking?

Comment: It is what I'm looking for.  The "...query existing DB to populate data..." would come from previous entries into the form I'm building. I'll have to back fill some data from this year to make it complete and then going forward the users will be responsible for adding new data.  Can a form have a table that is able to be filled in and changed on the fly?  I'll update the OP with what I would like to see.

Comment: Yes, a form can update a table on the fly. I don't know what you have already created, but I have some ideas about a solution. Trying to address all the issues in one of these comment boxes will be impossible, so at some point I can add an 'answer' that gets added to as other issues arise. (1) Do you currently have any code created? If so, post above. (2) Post your table names & field names, keys and relationships. To ponder: (a) I would only DISPLAY date rows on form thru current day; (b) Up to 70 columns? need scroll; (c) form for assoc. chems to units; <<continued below>>

Comment: (d) what happens if unit no longer tracks chem? show history or exclude from form?

Comment: Wayne, I will update the OP with what I have for Tables currently.

Comment: Wayne, to answer your questions.  (1) (2) Added to the OP. (a)(b)Displaying the previous 31 days of data would be fine, then in the longest month I would be showing the entire month.  (c) We wouldn't stop tracking a chemical for a unit, only add new to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101324/discussion-between-ben-a-and-wayne-g-dunn).